# sed replaces everything for first occurence argument and nothing for second occurence

Tags: linux, sed

I was trying to replace 'mysql' with 'MySQL' in the `/etc/snort/snort.conf` file and output the result to another file. There are two occurences of `mysql` in the file, as can be seen in the picture.

Whie using `sed s/mysql/MySQL/g /etc/snort/snort.conf > test.conf` did work, replacing `g` with `1` did the exact same thing instead of just replacing the first occurence. Moreover, using `2` replaced nothing instead of replacing the second occurence.

I'd appreciate some help in explaining this behavior..

EDIT: This is my text file: https://pastebin.com/X3R9HK6D

[image]

Comment: If it's text just include the text. Nothing in your picture needs color. The g is a switch for the regular expression and not the number of replaces that should be done.

Comment: I added a link to the text file in the original post. I cannot really follow what you meant, doesn't 'g' mean replace all occurences and a number written instead of 'g' mean that the number-th occurence should be replaced? That's what I read.

Comment: I don't really care about your text file, it was to point out that your screenshot is hard to read and can't be copied while only containing text. So post it as text if possible. Indent it 4 spaces to mark it as code to keep the format. Checking the [gnu page on sed and s](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) shows that I was wrong. Indeed your understanding seems to be correct. Did you try to pipe it using cat? So `cat snort.conf | sed ... > edit.conf` to see whenever it makes a difference`? what version of kali are you running?

Comment: I'll keep it in mind for the next question :). I have just tried it with grep and it has the same behavior. Still, what @Matt Wallis mentioned in his answer below seems to be the current behavior, but the GNU page you linked seems to say differently.. EDIT: My Kali version is 2019.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `1` flag means replace the first occurrence of the string on *each line*, not in the file as a whole. Similarly for the 2. The g flag also means replace all occurrences on each line. It just happens that this will also replace all occurrences in the file.

```
$ cat > text.txt
foo foo
foo foo
$ sed s/foo/bar/1 text.txt 
bar foo
bar foo
$ sed s/foo/bar/2 text.txt 
foo bar
foo bar
```

Comment: This perfectly explains the behavior. Thank you!

Comment: Wait, actually, why does this link @Seth mentioned above: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html actually show no mention of the 'each line' part? This is so strange..

Comment: @PhantomR. [gnu sed s docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) say 'pattern space', not each line, and not the whole file. For an understanding of pattern space, see [gnu sed execution cycle](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Execution-Cycle.html#Execution-Cycle)

Comment: There's a lengthy discussion about readling the whole file into the pattern space here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182195 . So, it can be done, but is not advisable! In your simple case, @PhantomR, the pattern space contains one line at a time.

Comment: That's good to know. If I may ask, is it possible that the behavior was once the one I originally assumed?

Comment: @PhantomR - no, sed has always been like this. It is a *stream editor*. That means it is designed to produce output from a continuous stream of input, reading it line by line, and processing it without waiting for the stream to end. It's been that way since 1973!